# Laravel Login works great on local machine but not on server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just copied my local Laravel project to a live server and encountered an issue I never had before.
When I try to login with the builtin laravel register/login form it redirects right back to the login form. It doesn't show an error, nor are there any errors in the log so i'm not sure what to look for. 
This has been driving me nuts all day.
I'm not sure which code to show but this is my `routes.php`

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

This is my `authenticate.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest())
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
        else
        {

            return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

My `authcontroller.php`

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {

            $this->auth = $auth;
            $this->registrar = $registrar;
            $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);

    }
```

I'm not sure what else I would need to show...

PS.
Just to make sure, I created a new user on the live server and tried to log in, didn't work either.
Can this be some token issue?

(Laravel 5.0.35)

Any help would be highly appreciated...
Thank you!

Comment: Do one thing, make a test route and put an echo on that route and see will it work or not?

Comment: The application itself works, that's not the problem. It's only the login. How would a test route help? (Or maybe I didn't fully understand your meaning)

Comment: All other routes work fine ?

Comment: Before doing anything else try to clean your browser cookies for the domain

Comment: How did you copy the project?

Comment: i think you have to clean your cache, try run: php artisan config:cache in the root 
 project folder

Comment: Anything in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?  And BTW did you make that [and the other dirs that need it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#install-laravel) writeable?

Comment: Yes everything else works just fine. Including registration BTW. Already cleared cache and tried in incognito. The project was copied via git at first and when it didn't work - via FTP.

Comment: I just realized that it does the same thing even for the wrong credentials. No errors or anything. As if it's missing the whole authenticate part of things...

Comment: Does it work with a clean 5.0 project on your server?

Comment: It works on the save server with a different application. Save laravel version